# Dealing with ReadableStream response from API cat-facts

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was doing a pretty easy task of getting information from an API but then i got the response as ReadableStream and things start to turn dark as always. I am trying to use the cat-facts API.

URL : https://alexwohlbruck.github.io/cat-facts/docs/

and render the results with VueJS. What i found on the internet but this code just return some random numbers.

Here is the code:

```
created() {
  this.getFacts();
},

methods: {
    getFacts() {
      let vm = this;

      fetch('http://localhost:8080/facts')
          .then(response => {

            const reader = response.body.getReader();
            return new ReadableStream({
              start(controller) {
                return pump();
                function pump() {
                  return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
                    // When no more data needs to be consumed, close the stream
                    if (done) {
                        controller.close();
                        return;
                    }
                    // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
                    vm.facts = value;
                    controller.enqueue(value);
                    return pump();
                  });
                }
              }  
            })
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
  },
 }
```

I am using vue.config.js to manage cors error:

```
module.exports =  {

devServers = {
    proxy: 'https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/'
}
}
```

I made the request with POSTMAN and worked just well.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do it like this:

```js
async getFacts() {
    let vm = this;

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/facts');
    const myJson = await response.json();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
}
```

Just wondring if you need to use `pump` at all.

**EDIT**

Without `async/await`

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8080/facts')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: that returns  "ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined"

Comment: I tried that already, POSTMAN returns an object that seems to be manageable in the way that you are suggesting, but shoud be something in the middle of this..

Comment: Oh you are probably getting that error because your env is not setup properly for `async/await`. Try the same using `.then()`

Comment: Could you explain it more?

Comment: Refresh the page and try the code below `EDIT` @francogiova

Answer (score 0):

I tried with ajax and a proxy made with php using guzzle to comunicate with the API and it worked! Just a simple line. But I am very confused about how fetch method works!